# View not returning to Base Adapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have my PurchaseListAdapter that extends base adapter, but when i call it in mine activity it doesn't enter in the getView and returns null when i call `listPurchase.setAdapter(adapter);`

Here it's my code.

Results.java

```
...     
 List<Purchase> purchases ;

     purchases = controller.getAll();

    listPurchase = new ListView(getBaseContext());  
    listPurchase = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_purchase);       

    adapter = new PurchaseListAdapter(MainActivity.mContext, purchases); 
    listPurchase.setAdapter(adapter);   //It's returning null here
```

PurchaseListAdapter.java

```
public class PurchaseListAdapter  extends BaseAdapter
{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Purchase> mItens;

    //Labels
    private TextView lbl_tittle;
    private TextView lbl_current_tittle;
    private TextView lbl_performance_tittle;

    //TextView
    private TextView gas_liters;
    private TextView gas_price;
    private TextView performance;
    private TextView total_kilometers;

    //private ImageView imgStatus;

    //private Button btnHistory;

    //Fonts
    Typeface nexaBold;
    Typeface nexaLight;

    public PurchaseListAdapter( Context ctx, List<Purchase> itens) {
        this.mItens = itens;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return this.mItens.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return this.mItens.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchase_element, null);

        gas_liters = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.element_gas_liters);
        gas_price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.element_gas_price);
        performance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.element_perfomance);
        total_kilometers = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.element_total_kilometers);




        //LoadingFonts
        nexaBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(MainActivity.mContext.getAssets(), "nexa_bold.otf");
        nexaLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(MainActivity.mContext.getAssets(), "nexa_light.otf");

        setFonts(view);




        //Loading Views
        gas_liters.setText(mItens.get(position).getGas().toString() + "L");
        gas_price.setText("R$" + mItens.get(position).getGasPrice()+"");


        if(position == 0)
            performance.setText("First time");

        else
        {
            double result = (mItens.get(position).getKilometers() - (mItens.get(position-1).getKilometers()))
                        / Double.parseDouble(mItens.get(position).getGas());

        //Checar
        performance.setText(result+" KM/L");
        }



        total_kilometers.setText(mItens.get(position).getKilometers()+" KM");

        lbl_tittle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.element_tittle);
        lbl_tittle.setText(mItens.get(position).getDate().toString() + " - " + mItens.get(position).getTime().toString());



        return view;
    }
```

the xml files:

The row:
purchase_element.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/element_tittle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"        
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:text=""
        />

    <View 
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/element_tittle"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="#20000000"
        />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.28" >   

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/element_current_tittle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"         
            android:background="@null"
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textSize="23dp"
            android:text="Current"
            />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_gas" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/element_current_tittle"
            android:src="@drawable/gasoline"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/element_gas_liters"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"          
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_below="@id/element_current_tittle"          
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_gas"
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textSize="21dp"
            android:text=""
            />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/element_gas_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"          
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_below="@id/element_gas_liters"
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textSize="21dp"
            android:text=""
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View 
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:background="#20000000"
            />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.28" >

          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/element_perfomance_tittle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="08dp"           
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="Perfomance"
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textSize="23dp" />


        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/element_perfomance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"          
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_below="@id/element_perfomance_tittle"                    
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textSize="21dp"
            android:text=""
            />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/element_total_kilometers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"          
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_below="@id/element_perfomance"
            android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
            android:textSize="19dp"
            android:text=""
            />


    </RelativeLayout>



    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

The ListView:

purchase_list_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/gas_station_main_bg">

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/list_purchase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is `controller.getAll()`? Are you sure this returns a `ArrayList` that contains items?

Comment: It returns  List<Purchase> purchases = new ArrayList<Purchase>(); from the database. I checked and it's returning correctly the values. Inside the baseAdapter i checked the getCount() and the list, and it's returning ok.

Comment: So, what is this issue here? The list is not displayed? You have an Exception? Provide more detail please, along your your activity / fragment code.

Comment: Like i said up there, when my code gets in listPurchase.setAdapter(adapter); in the Results activity it  gives an Exception, nullpointer exception in that line. When i debuged in the adapter, it doesn't enter in the getView(), i think that it's the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that your listPurchase is not null ?

Comment: The listPurchase is null when it calls the setAdapter(),but the values is there, but i don't know what to do.

Comment: `listPurchase` must be null. Are you sure that your Activity uses purchase_list_view.xml?

Comment: Yes, it is using purchase_list_view.xml, the R.id.list_purchase.